# htaccess redirect to index.php & force https/www problems

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess file, I'm trying to achieve 2 things:-

### 1) Redirect any path to /index.php and pass the path as a query string, but keep the original URL

For example `example.com/foo/bar` would result in `example.com/index.php?foo/bar` behind the scenes but still show `example.com/foo/bar` in the address bar as the URL.

### 2) Enforce https & www

For example `http://example.com/foo/bar` would result in `https://www.example.com/index.php?foo/bar` behind the scenes but would show `https://www.example.com/foo/bar` in the address bar as the URL.

Below is what I have so far.

```
# Redirect to index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# When http isn't specified, it redirects to file with same URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA]

## If no http2
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
## Or if http_host isn't www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
## Then rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

With this, the redirect to index.php works as intended provided `https` and `www` are present in the original URL. This is because only the first rule block is triggered, whilst the second is skipped.

Though if either `https` or `www` aren't present, the resulting URL in the address bar is `https://www.example.com/index.php?foo/bar` not `https://www.example.com/foo/bar` as both rule blocks are triggered.

I'm wondering if these 2 different .htaccess rule blocks can be combined into one which fulfils the original requirements?

Thanks

Comment: You need to do these things in opposite order … Place the HTTPS redirect first, and the internal rewrite to the index.php after that.

Comment: @CBroe saying correct. Need to maintain order is important. Added rewriting rule for #1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
# non www to www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# foo/bar to index.php?a=foo&b=bar

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
```

For more rewriting URL logic use this https://www.301-redirect.online/htaccess-rewrite-generator

Recommended tool : https://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Comment: Welcome. Use this tool for longer run it will helpful